# how to configure static lan ip to different router provided by isp?

Tags: router, switch, local-area-network, isp, wide-area-network

We have got Vodafone Internet ISP. We asked for 5 public ip's.

They had provided 1 wan ip and 5 lan ip pool.

WAN Configured and internet working but LAN ip how to use, i need 5 static ip address to use for 5 different devices.

Answer (score 1):

Set up devices with static addresses manually, or use DHCP. Use the addresses assigned to you.

[Vodafone's static IP CPE screenshots](https://www.vodafone.co.uk/business/media/document/vodafone-business-broadband-ip-user-guide_amended.pdf) imply enabling this is hidden under expert settings, "LAN Public", "Multiple Static IP".

---

Also consider implementing IPv6, which sadly is not visible in the Vodafone screenshots I found. Easier to understand when everything, including LAN devices, are assigned public IP addresses.